# Insert new instance of unordered_map into unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have these construction:

```
typedef std::unordered_set<std::string> functionSet;

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, functionSet> classMap;

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, classMap> semanticMap;
```

I have a map with class names, it contains map with function names and it contains set with variables, I'm using it for semantic analysis in my code.
When there is a situation, when new "class" is defined, I'm calling function that adds new class to semnaticMap, so it means it has to add key value pair to semanticMap, name of the class and new instance of classMap, but I don't know how to do it.

I have a variable semanticMap map. So I've tried `map.insert("name", new classMap), std::make_pair()`, etc. but everything show me error that

> ```
> No matching member function for call to 'insert'.
> ```

I want to add to unordered_map "key" => new_unordered_map.

Comment: Post a [mcve] reproducing your error as required here please.

Comment: `new classMap` is a `classMap*` but `semanticMap` contains `classMap`s. Dont use `new`. voting to close as typo

Comment: `new` gives you a pointer. `insert` takes an instance (by reference) and makes a copy of it inside the container.

Comment: btw to avoid the copy you can use `emplace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map contains `classMap` type as values, not `classMap*` (which is the result of expression `new classMap`). The following code will work for you:

```
map.insert({"name", classMap()});
```